# Regular Expression to extract snippet around search term

Tags: regex

We need a regular expression to select sentences from a text where we are searching for a specific term or phrase. The result should have the line with the search term as well as the preceding and succeeding line. The definition of line here can be anything starting from empty line to any character.

For example if we are searching for the term "deposition"(case insensitive) in the below text:

```
12           xxxxxxxxxx.           )
13   ______________________________)
14
15
16
17
18             VIDEOTAPE DEPOSITION OF JOHN
19                    FRIDAY, OCTOBER 30, 2009
20
21
22
23
24   PAGES 1 - 92
```

this should return me the following result:

```
17
18             VIDEOTAPE DEPOSITION OF JOHN
19                    FRIDAY, OCTOBER 30, 2009
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
[^\r\n]*?(?:\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]*?\bDEPOSITION\b[^\r\n]*?(?:\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]*?(?:\r|\n|\r\n)
```

Replace the word you're looking for with `DEPOSITION` each time. In order to make the search case insensitive, you need to set it up in the regular expression engine of your choice.

Here's a [live demo](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?33lou).

Comment: Or `/^.*\n.*deposition.*\n.*\n/mi` if you want something simpler.

Comment: @melpomene yes. in terms of my answer the look-ahead part was enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a piece of something you are searching you can use the following:

```
(\n^.+?DEPOSITION.+?$\n.+?\n)
```

If you just want to match all of the groups you can replace the specific term with \S (non-space character) as so:

```
(\n^.+?\S.+?$\n.+?\n)
```

In both cases it is important to ensure you have "Dot Matches Newline" turned OFF. In the above, the \n are newlines, .+? will match anything until the following character, ^ matches the beginning of a line and $ matches the end of a line.  The only other gotcha might be a Regex interpreter that has a flag for switching ^ and $ to match the beginning and end of a file rather than a line. This should default to off, but it's worth making sure